# php pdo insert statements failing and im not getting any errors

Tags: php, pdo

i have what should be a very simple pdo insert statement which is failing. im not getting any php errors although i do not know how to integrate pdo error handling into this script

i have confirmed that the data is being recieved from the form. and if you look at my code everything is working including the basic validation. it goes wrong when i try to insert. i have been on the computer for the last two hours trying various pdo error reporting techniques that i have found online and none of them are working

```
<?php

$DSN = "mysql:host = localHost; dbname=cms";
$connect = new PDO($DSN, 'root', '');
?>


<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true); // set to false in production
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<?php


  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $postTitle = $_POST["postTitle"];
    $category  = $_POST["category"];
    $image     = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $target    = "uploads/".basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $postDescription = $_POST["postDescription"];
    $admin = "cole";
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Dublin");
    $currenttime = time();
    $datetime= strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", $currenttime);

    if(empty($postTitle)){
      $_SESSION["error"] = "please add a post title";
      redirect("addnewpost.php");
    }elseif(strlen($postTitle)<5){
      $_SESSION["error"] = "post title must be longer than 5 charachters";
      redirect("addnewpost.php");
    }elseif(strlen($postDescription)>999){
      $_SESSION["error"] = "post must be less than 1000 charachters";
      redirect("addnewpost.php");
    }else {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO posts(datetime,title,category,author,image,post) VALUES(:entrytime,:postTitle,:postCategory,:adminName,:pic,:postText)";


      $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(':entrytime',$datetime);
      $stmt->bindValue(':postTitle',$postTitle);
      $stmt->bindValue(':postCategory',$category);
      $stmt->bindValue(':admiNname',$admin);
      $stmt->bindValue(':pic',$image);
      $stmt->bindValue(':postText',$postDescription);
      $Execute = $stmt->execute();



      if($Execute){
        $_SESSION["success"] = "data added successfully";
        redirect("addnewpost.php");
      }else {
    print_r($connect->errorInfo());
        $_SESSION["error"] = "something went wrong. data not added to table";
        redirect("addnewpost.php");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if PDO is case sensitive in bind names but you have `adminName` and `admiNname`.

Comment: PDO reports errors differently than PHP. You need to explicitly check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: `%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S` is not a mysql datetime format. What DB are you using and what datatype is `datetime`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following when you create the PDO statement.

```php
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then you can put your query in a `try/catch` block and see the actual error. Either catch `Exception` or `PDOException`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong `$DSN = "mysql:host = localHost; dbname=cms";` try it with lowercase localhost

interestingly, I just did a bit of testing on this and it looks like you can have a space with the host, but not the database name but it doesn't return an error, just an empty PDO object e.g. if I var dump this:

```
PDO("mysql:host = $host;dbname =$dbname;charset=utf8mb4", $user, $pass)
```

I get `object(PDO)#2 (0) { }` but it doesn't fall into my

`catch(PDOException $e) {` block, just leaving me with a white screen of death (aside from my var dump)

however this: `PDO("mysql:host = $host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4", $user, $pass);` connects perfectly.

At the end of the day it's simpler, and more standard I think, to have no spaces.  But this lack of a PDOException is worth noting for anyone else having a similar problem